# Adding buttons dynamically in stacklayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to add a button dynamically in `StackLayout` when "add" button is clicked. I wrote `stacklayoutname.children.add(button)`, it does not giving me the thing i am looking for.

In xaml:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="layout">
    <Button Text="add" Clicked="Addbutton"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In code:

```
private void Addbutton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
     var layout = new StackLayout();
     var btn = new Button { Text = "New button", FontSize = 30, TranslationY = 30 };
     this.Content = layout;
     layout.Children.Add(btn);
}
```

It is giving only new button and add button is disappearing, but I want whenever we click on add button it should give number of new button equal to the number of clicks on add button.

Comment: It disappears because it's being replaced by the new `StackLayout`. And when you say _should give number of new button equal to the number of clicks on add button_, do you mean you want to add buttons as per each click or just display number of clicks on `Button`'s `Text`?

Comment: thanks for response,yeah i wanted to add those many buttons as  number of clicks but not just display number of clicks on Button's Text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you already have a StackLayout, there's no need to add a new one, because it replaces the old one if you do. The following will add a button to the `StackLayout` on every button click.

```
// Define a field for StackLayout
StackLayout parent;

public void Addbutton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define a new button
    Button newButton = new Button { Text = "New Button" };

    // Creating a binding
    newButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding ("ViewModelProperty"));

    // Set the binding context after SetBinding method calls for performance reasons
    newButton.BindingContext = viewModel;

    // Set StackLayout in XAML to the class field
    parent = layout;

    // Add the new button to the StackLayout
    parent.Children.Add(newButton);
}
```

For more information about Binding, check out [BindableObject Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/) and [Data Binding Basics](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/).

Comment: Thanks it got worked for me.but i would like add command for that newly added button.Is it possible to bind the commands for those buttons

Comment: How to give bindings to these buttons

Comment: To add binds (Continuing the AddButton method): `newButton.BindingContext = yourViewModel;` and `newButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("CommandPropertyName"));`

Comment: @sahithi Yes, it is possible. Please check my updated answer. :)