# ControlTemplate overrides controls added programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I Am trying to create a dummy app that has multiple "Branding Packages".
I have read that using a control template is the easiest way to apply a global styling to the app. most controls in the app will be added dynamically via the code behind.

However whenever I set the content view to use the control template none of the controls I have added via code will display

Here is the App.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestWebApp.App">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="Template">
        <Grid>
          <Label Text="Control Template Demo App"
                 TextColor="White">
          </Label>
          <ContentPresenter/>
          <BoxView Color="Teal" />
          <Label Text="(c) WTF 2018"
                 TextColor="White"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here is the MainPage.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWebApp"
             x:Class="TestWebApp.MainPage">
  <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource Template}">

    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="MenuLayout">

      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestWebApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Object> testList = TestMethod();
            foreach(Object testObject in testList)
            {
                MenuLayout.Children.Add((View)testObject);
            }
        }
        public List<Object> TestMethod()
        {
            Button newButton = new Button {Text = "This is a Test Button", BackgroundColor = Color.White};
            List<Object> returnList = new List<object>();
            returnList.Add(newButton);
            return returnList;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically create a page from the code behind while still implementing the control template

Comment: From code , you want to add Button to StackLayout.Have a try this.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229706/adding-buttons-dynamically-in-stacklayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some `RowDefinitions` to the `Grid` in the template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Template">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Text="Control Template Demo App" TextColor="White" />
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
        <BoxView Color="Teal" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Label Text="(c) WTF 2018" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: this did fix the issue. I now just need to properly format the control template to act as a global style sheet for my purposes