# Xamarin Forms: Can I make a custom template that can be dynamically altered by different pages?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to create a sort of template that has a header and body where the body is fully implemented by a page and the header has areas that can be added to by the page.

I'm currently experimenting with a ControlTemplate which look like this:

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="60*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <BoxView BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

        <StackLayout x:Name="LeftHeaderArea" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Label Text="{DynamicResource HeaderTitle}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
        <StackLayout x:Name="RightHeaderArea" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" />
      </Grid>

      <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

I can use this ControlTemplate in my XAML views and pages to build the body, but I haven't found any way to access `LeftHeaderArea` or `RightHeaderArea` to add controls to them.

Comment: Do you want to add control templates dynamically or do you want to dynamically add things to the control template?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Dynamically add things (buttons) to the control template.

Comment: If in `StackLayout` , you can try this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229706/adding-buttons-dynamically-in-stacklayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having each page inject controls into the header, we decided to let the header define all the possible controls and only make visible the ones which are accessible in a given page.

For example, my question's `RightHeaderArea` has been refactored to look like this:

```
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" HorizontalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2">
          <svg:SvgCachedImage VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" 
                              IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.AvailableToolbarCommands, Converter={StaticResource tclsToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static mod:ToolbarCommandName.ViewUploadHistory}}" 
                              Source="resource://Uploader.Images.icon-viewUploadHistory.svg">
            <svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.AvailableToolbarCommands, Converter={StaticResource tclsToCommandConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static mod:ToolbarCommandName.ViewUploadHistory}}" />
            </svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
          </svg:SvgCachedImage>

          <svg:SvgCachedImage VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="35"
                              IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.AvailableToolbarCommands, Converter={StaticResource tclsToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static mod:ToolbarCommandName.ViewUploadQueue}}" 
                              Source="resource://Uploader.Images.icon-viewUploadQueue.svg">
            <svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.AvailableToolbarCommands, Converter={StaticResource tclsToCommandConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static mod:ToolbarCommandName.ViewUploadQueue}}" />
            </svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
          </svg:SvgCachedImage>

          <svg:SvgCachedImage Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="50" 
                              IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.AvailableToolbarCommands, Converter={StaticResource tclsToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static mod:ToolbarCommandName.Upload}}" 
                              Source="resource://Uploader.Images.icon-upload.svg">
            <svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.AvailableToolbarCommands, Converter={StaticResource tclsToCommandConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static mod:ToolbarCommandName.Upload}}" />
            </svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
          </svg:SvgCachedImage>
        </StackLayout>
```

All my ViewModels have a public property `AvailableToolbarCommands` which is a `List<ToolbarCommandLink>` where `ToolbarCommandLink` is a simple class that contains a `Command` and a custom enum value (`ToolbarCommandName`).

To make it all work are the converters. `tclsToBoolConverter` returns true if the value (List) contains a ToolbarCommandLink with a name that matches the parameter (ToolbarCommandName); `tclsToCommandConverter` returns the Command in the ToolbarCommandLink it finds in the value (List) which matches the parameter.